# Find the matrix for $T$ relative to the basis $B^{'}$

Tags: linear-algebra

$[T]_{B}=\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 0\\ 
1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$, $P_{B\to B^{'}}=\begin{bmatrix}
3 & 2\\ 
1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$, Using the formula $[T]_{B^{'}}=P_{B\to B^{'}}[T]_{B}P_{B^{'}\to B}$ and using $P_{B^{'}\to B}=(P_{B\to B^{'}})^{-1}$ I get

$$[T]_{B^{'}}=\begin{bmatrix}
3 & 2\\ 
1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 0\\ 
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -2\\ 
-1 & 3
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
4 & -6\\ 
1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}$$

Unfortunately this is not the correct answer and I'm clueless as to where I went wrong.

Comment: You made a typo in matrix $T$ in the entry [2,1], when computing product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems a typo. Correcting $[T]_B$ we have:

$$[T]_{B^{'}}=\begin{bmatrix}
3 & 2\\ 
1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 0\\ 
\color{red}1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -2\\ 
-1 & 3
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
6 & -10\\ 
2 & -3
\end{bmatrix}$$